# How to correctly use modules in rdd.map with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

As the title suggests, I'm trying to create external modules which are afterwards imported and invoked in a simple `rdd.map` function. An example below:

```
## main.py ##
myrdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("myModule.py")

import myModule as mm

myrdd.map(lambda x: mm.Module.test(x)).collect()

## myModule.py ##
class Module():
    def test(self,x):
       return x * 2
```

When trying to run this with spark submit I get the following error:

```
test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Can someone point the error out?

Thank you very much

Comment: test is a method, not a class method. You cannot use it like this as it needs self as first argument. It is python error, not pyspark error.

Answer (score 0):

test() is not a class method, so you can't call Module.test(x) directly.

Instead create an Module object and call the test() method on it as below:

```
myrdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("myModule.py")
import myModule as mm

myrdd.map(lambda x: mm.Module().test(x)).collect()
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```